# paypal not returning to url specified in settings

Tags: paypal, eclipse-pdt

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">  
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="address@gmail.com" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="company - product" />
<input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="0.01" />
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="GBP" />
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mywebsite.com/folder/success.php" /> 
<input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://mywebsite.com/folder//booking.html" />
<input type="hidden" name="bn" value="company_BuyNow_product_UK" /> 
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" name="submit" alt="Buy Now" /> 
</form>
```

I've set Website Payment Preferences > Auto Return for Website Payments > radio button to 'on'.
I've also set the redirect url to match my button code:

```
<input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://mywebsite.com/folder/success.php" />
```

When the button is clicked, the browser redirects to paypal, shows my product details correctly and allows me to pay, then it says 'Review your information' while the loading wheel spins for around fifteen seconds, a payment received conformation email comes to me, then nothing happens, the wheel keeps spinning over and over indefinatly stuck on the 'Review your information' screen never redirecting to my return url...

Not found anything related on google or here or paypal docs.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm seeing the very same behaviour.

Comment: no dude... try google these guys, way better support > gocardless

Answer (score 0):

Have you verified your test seller's email address in the Sandbox?

Log into the Sandbox Click on test accounts; Select the seller account; Click on Enter Sandbox Test Site; Log in as the Sandbox seller; Verify the email (check the Sandbox > Test Emails for the confirmation email and the confirmation code); Use the link on the confirmation page to manually enter the confirmation code

Hope this helps.